# KeyPress Event gives wrong value

Tags: c#, decimal, keypress

I made a KeyPress Event and want to allow only Double values (or just digits and comma) so I tried this:

```
 e.Handled = !(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Decimal);
```

But somehow he's got problems with the "Decimal". I'm using a german keyboard and when I try to enter the comma, he does nothing. When I press the "n" key he writes the letter. What is wrong here and how to solve that?

Comment: Can you show the whole Event-Handler Method pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can restrict the input using `keyPress` event like so:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   char c= e.KeyChar;
   if (!char.IsDigit(c) && !char.IsControl(c))
   {
      e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

if we want to extend our restriction condition to accept a certain character (for example `,`)

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  char c= e.KeyChar;
  if (!char.IsDigit(c) && !char.IsControl(c) && c!=',')
  {
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

To avoid having multiple comma like `222,34545,454` we can do this work around:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  char c= e.KeyChar;
  bool comma= textBox1.Text.Contains(','); //true in case comma already inserted

  // accepts only digits, controls and comma
  if (!char.IsDigit(c) && !char.IsControl(c) && c!=',')
  {
    e.Handled = true;
    return;
  }


  // whenever a comma is inserted we check if we already have one
  if (c == ',' && comma)
  {
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Then show more Code and tell us where exactly is the problem... you only showed the e.Handled line

Comment: Ah ok the edited one works fine. Thank you a lot! - I posted that before you edited your post

Comment: Suggestion, in this case using Preview KeyPress will be better

Comment: Thanks! I would have tried to throw an exception but thats much better!